# How to remove the key/value pair from a List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` like the following.

```
[{a=1, b=Kanji, c=null, d=Alphabet}]
```

I already know "c" key sometimes has the value = `null`, so I want to delete "c" key from `List<Map<String, Object>>` if that is the case.

So I want the result like if "c" key has the value = "null" or empty

`[{a=1, b=Kanji, d=Alphabet}]`

So I tried

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = ....(procedure to get the  [{a=1, b=Kanji, c=null, d=Alphabet}] from sql)

for (Map<String, Object> child : list) {
    Object value = child.get("c");
      if(value == null || value == "") {
        list.remove("c");
      }
}
```

But the List still shows

```
[{a=1, b=Kanji, c=null, d=Alphabet}]
```

How can I remove the value "c" from the list?

I want to get the consequence as `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: A List of a Map is just silly.  Just using a Map

Comment: You have `c` in `child`, not `List`.  So you should be doing `child.remove("c")`.  Also, please consider camelCasing your variable names, or at least not using variable names that clash with class names.

Comment: @ScaryWombat FYI Spring JdbcTemplate also returns List<Map> on queryForList

Comment: In addition to trying to remove from the List and not the Map, you also have a bug with your comparison for an empty string. You should use `value.equals("")`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick response and detail.

Comment: @ReiKudo In addition to thanking everyone (much appreciated I'm sure), make sure you pick an answer so that the answeree is rewarded.

Comment: Well, I've selected the much informative one, but thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes need..**

> 1. Remove from the `map`, instead of removing from the `list`.
> 2. Iterate over the `key` to find the map element with value as `null`

**Try This..**

```
for(Map<String, Object> child : List){
    for(String key : child.keySet()){
                if(child.get(key)==null)
                    child.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Removes any key with a null value, not just 'c'.

Comment: @dave but not good enough. It could have been even better if we override put function and validate while inserting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the element from the child map (`child.remove("c")`) instead of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above tries to remove the key from the list, but it should be trying to remove the key from the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<String, String>();
    abc.put("number", "hello");
    abc.put("value", "there");
    List<Map<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    mylist.add(abc);
    System.out.println(mylist);
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
        mylist.get(i).keySet().removeIf(key -> key == "number");
    }
    System.out.println(mylist)
------------------------------output------------------------
[{number=hello, value=there}]
[{value=there}]
```